# Issue: Redis JSON CLI SET command to update a variable in object

Tags: redis, node-redis, redisjson, redis-stack-server

`[ { "senderID": "64d9c926c17fd183a93d5e35", "receiverID": "64d9c92dc17fd183a93d5e39", "timestamp": "2023-08-14T07:39:45.946Z", "content": "bru", "status": "delivered", "type": "chat", "messageID": "8188946b-67e4-4d86-a927-32842361825c" }, ... ]`

```
JSON.SET rooms:64d9c926c17fd183a93d5e35-64d9c92dc17fd183a93d5e39 $[?(@.status=='sent')].status "'delivered'"
```

[Redis JSON Query Image on redis cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3X2i.png)

I do get that error -
Invalid argument(s): closing quote must be followed by a space or nothing at all

I have tried the variations of delivered and sent mentioned in the query
with double quotes, single quotes, and both for the sake of it

Wrong Query? idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your JSONPath has single quotes in it. Try wrapping it in double quotes. Like this:

```bash
JSON.SET rooms:64d9c926c17fd183a93d5e35-64d9c92dc17fd183a93d5e39 "$[?(@.status=='sent')].status" '"delivered"'
```

Also, I changed the string to use single quotes on the outside. Since double quotes are in JSON all over the place, I always wrap my JSON in single quotes. Just a good habit.

Comment: OMG that's so much, i don't realize that the condition itself needed the double quotes, you are awesome have a great years ahead, (i usually use double quotes on outside, i got this query when wandering in internet mybad}